# Margin on a div with width 100% height 100% inside another div with width 100% height 100%

Tags: html, css, margin, centering

I a building a site with a video as a background. I want all divs to be centered and responsive  and that's why I am using width and height 100%. I then have an overlaying div that fades in and out on click using jquery. My problem is that I can't seem to get an even margin around this div after it has faded in. The div I want margin on has the id "info".

My html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content=""/>
        <meta name="keywords"content=""/>
        <title></title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#info").fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <header>
        <div id="nav">
            <p><a id="btn" href="#">+</a></p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="info">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <video id="video_background" src="vid/147000037.mp4" autoplay>
</html>
```

and my css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight","HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

}

header {
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #000000;
}

#nav {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    color: #000000;
}


#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#video_background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1000;
}

#info {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.97);
    z-index: 900;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 10px;
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your infobox has fixed positioning you can omit the height/width and margin in your css and use the offsets to create a responsive container with nice margin. Just change your `#info` css to the following:

```
#info {
   /* omit height & width */
   background: #bada55; /* Just because white on white is tough to see */
   z-index: 900;
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   /* omit margin and use according offsets */
   top:15px;left:15px;right:15px;bottom:15px;
   vertical-align: center;
}
```

See it [working here](http://jsfiddle.net/VU3PU/).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you Christoph!

Comment: @user2273444 why you don't accept this answer as correct? it's a way to say "thanks" here on S.O.